# Making the size of desktop app window stay the same

Tags: java, swing, window, desktop

I am developing desktop Java application using NetBeans JBuilder. I make the contents of the program (front page) to fit in a relatively small window. I am using GridBagLayout. Once I run the program and zoom it in with the button on the right top hand side of the window the program takes all the screen of my laptop. But the contents looks like a mess. I want to deny zoom in once it is pressed i.e. I want my program to stay in the same size no matter whether you zoom it in or not.
How to do that?

Comment: It all depends on your frame (JFrame) definition. I guess it is about Java Swing, if so please add the swing tag...

Comment: *How to do that?* By using the appropriate gridbag constraints, or by making the frame not resizable as you were told in a deleted answer. There is no Netbeans JBuilder. There is Netbeans, and there is JBuilder. Two different programs.

Answer (score 3):

> The program by default does not extend JFrame or JDialog. It is using Swing Application Framework library which is made part of project. It extends FrameView class.

You should really try RTM. I don't use this abandoned API, yet it took just a few seconds to discover...  [`FrameView.getFrame()`](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/net/java/dev/appframework/appframework/1.03/appframework-1.03-javadoc.jar!/org/jdesktop/application/FrameView.html#getFrame%28%29).

Then of course, you can use Jeffrey's advice of [`Frame.setResizable(boolean)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setResizable%28boolean%29).

Comment: I didn't realize that `FrameView` has a `Frame` backing it. Undeleted as per request. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

[`Frame#setResizable(false);`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setResizable%28boolean%29)
[`Dialog#setResizable(false);`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.html)

Comment: The program by default does not extend JFrame or JDialog. It is using Swing Application Framework library which is made part of project. It extends FrameView class.

Answer (score 1):

you should use `Frame.setResizable(false)` 
and set the size of frame to maximize size

```
Dimension d=getMaximumSize();
Frame.setSize(d.width, d.height);
```